# Flutter app crash on IOS simulator without error when calling GoogleMLKit LanguageID

Tags: ios, flutter, google-mlkit

My flutter app crash on IOS simulator without any error message when calling LanguageIdentifier.identifyLanguage(text). The app works fine on Android.

Pubspec.yaml line is google_mlkit_language_id: ^0.5.0.

Code is:

```
final _languageIdentifier = LanguageIdentifier(confidenceThreshold: 0.5);

...

Future<String?> _identifyLanguage(String text) async {
    //if (text == '') return;
    String? language;
    try {
      language = await _languageIdentifier.identifyLanguage(text);
    } catch (e) {
      print('error: ${e.toString()}');
    }
    return language;
  }
```

I also added the line to the pod file:

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/LanguageID'
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
```

Any tips on how to fix and how to debug when IOS suddenly crash without any message?

I am running on mac mini m2 with Android studio and xcode.